How do I get a good performance for my game?
I'm working on a game right now. The game has 4 cells for weighing somebody on a plate and controls actuators. These are balancing a platform. The platform itself has a maze for a little ball and you have to tend your body to control the ball to the goal. I have a problem since I made a function, which asks a proximity switch, if the ball is in the goal. The Stopwatch in my Tkinter GUI is lagging, I tried to set the delays a bit higher but nothing helps. If I comment out the function for asking the goal, stopwatch works fine. Maybe you can help me. :)
from tkinter import *
from datetime import datetime
import os
import time
#from playsound import playsound
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import versuch

button_pressed = False
# Erstellen des Hauptfensters
root = Tk()
root.title("Geschicklichkeitsspiel")
root.configure(background="white")

# Automatisch einstellen der Fenstergröße und Position
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
root.geometry("{}x{}".format(root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()))

# Erstellen des Start-Buttons und Abfrage ob Ball am Start
def start_button_click():
    if versuch.start() == False:
        return
    else:
        open_game_state()
def diff_change():
    pass
    
def open_game_state():

    game_window = Toplevel(root)
    game_window.title("Game")
    game_window.configure(background="white")
    game_window.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
 
    header_label = Label(game_window, image=image1, bg="white")
    header_label.pack(pady=10)

    stopwatch_label = Label(game_window, text="00:00.000", font=("Helvetica", 100, "bold"), pady=50, bg="white", fg="#32439B")
    stopwatch_label.pack(pady=50)

    stop_button = Button(game_window, text="Abbrechen", font=("Helvetica", 36), bg="#D33F49", fg="white", padx=30, pady=20, command=game_window.destroy, takefocus=False)
    stop_button.pack(pady=50)
    def goal_check():
        if game_window.winfo_exists():
            if versuch.goal() == True:
                game_window.destroy()
            else:
                versuch.update_servos()
            root.after(100, goal_check)
    
    # Startzeit für Stopwatch
    global start_time
    start_time = datetime.now()
    #Spiellogik
    
        
    # Aktualisieren der Stopwatch-Anzeige
    global stopwatch_running
    stopwatch_running = True
    update_stopwatch(stopwatch_label)
    goal_check()
    
   
        
def update_stopwatch(stopwatch_label):
    # Aktualisieren der Stopwatch-Anzeige
    try:
        if stopwatch_running:
            elapsed_time = datetime.now() - start_time
            stopwatch_str = "{:02d}:{:02d}.{:03d}".format(
                elapsed_time.seconds // 60, elapsed_time.seconds % 60, elapsed_time.microseconds // 1000)
            stopwatch_label.configure(text=stopwatch_str)
            # Weiter aktualisieren der Stopwatch-Anzeige
            root.after(10, update_stopwatch, stopwatch_label)
    except TypeError:
        print("error")

def open_settings():
    
     # Schließen des Einstellungs-Fensters
    def close_settings():
        settings_window.destroy()


    def shutdown(): 
        time.sleep(3)
        os.system('shutdown -s')

    def diff_change():
        global button_pressed
        if button_pressed == False:
            button_pressed = True
            diff_button.configure(fg="red", activeforeground="red")

        else:
            button_pressed = False
            diff_button.configure(fg="green", activeforeground="green")

    # Erstellen des Einstellungs-Fensters
    settings_window = Toplevel(root)
    settings_window.title("Einstellungen")
    settings_window.configure(background="white")
    settings_window.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
    

    # Setzen des Headers
    settings_header_label = Label(settings_window, text="Einstellungen", font=("Helvetica", 50, "bold"), pady=20, bg="white", fg="#32439B")
    settings_header_label.pack()

    # Erstellen des Reset-Buttons
    reset_button = Button(settings_window, text="Reset", font=("Helvetica", 30), bg="#32439B", fg="white",activebackground="#32439B",activeforeground="white", padx=20, pady=20, takefocus=False)
    reset_button.pack(pady=20)
    # Erstellen des Herunterfahren-Button
    shutdown_button = Button(settings_window, text="Herunterfahren", font=("Helvetica", 30), bg="#32439B", fg="white" ,activebackground="#32439B",activeforeground="white",padx=20, pady=20, takefocus=False)
    shutdown_button.pack(pady=20)
    # Erstellen des Schwierigkeits-Button
    diff_button = Button(settings_window, text="Schwierigkeit", font=("Helvetica", 30), bg="#32439B", fg="green", activebackground="#32439B",activeforeground="green",padx=20, pady=20, command=diff_change, takefocus=False)
    diff_button.pack(pady=20)
    # Erstellen des Zurückbuttons
    back_icon = PhotoImage(file="./assets/Back.png").subsample(3,3)
    back_button = Button(settings_window,borderwidth=0,highlightthicknes=0, image=back_icon, bg="white", bd=0,activebackground="white", command=close_settings, takefocus=False)
    back_button.place(relx=1, rely=0.88, anchor=SE, x=-10, y=-10)

    # Blockieren des Hauptfensters, bis das Einstellungs-Fenster geschlossen wird
    root.wait_window(settings_window)


# Erstellen der Überschrift
header_label = Label(root, text="Kannst du die Challenge meistern?", font=("Helvetica", 24, "bold"), pady=20, bg="white", fg="#32439B")
header_label.pack(pady=(20,0))

# Hinzufügen des oberen Bilds
image1 = PhotoImage(file="./assets/Schriftzug.png").subsample(4, 4)
header_label = Label(root, image=image1, bg="white")
header_label.pack(pady=10)

button_frame = Frame(root, bg="white")
button_frame.pack(pady=20)

start_button = Button(button_frame, text="Start", font=("Helvetica", 36), bg="#32439B",activebackground="#32439B", fg="white",activeforeground="white", padx=30, pady=20, width=10, command=start_button_click, takefocus=False)
start_button.pack(side=LEFT, pady=(100,0))

# Erstellen des Zahnrads
gear_icon = PhotoImage(file="./assets/GearIcon.png").subsample(30, 30)
gear_button = Button(root, image=gear_icon,borderwidth=0,highlightthicknes=0, bg="white",activebackground="white",bd=0, command=open_settings, takefocus=False)
gear_button.place(relx=1, rely=0.88, anchor=SE, x=-10, y=-10)

# Starten der GUI
root.mainloop()


import tkinter as tk
from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import serial

# Set up GPIO pins for servo control
servoX_pin = 18
servoY_pin = 19
servo_pulse = 1500

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(servoX_pin, GPIO.OUT)
pwm_x = GPIO.PWM(servoX_pin, 50)
pwm_x.start(0)

GPIO.setup(servoY_pin, GPIO.OUT)
pwm_y = GPIO.PWM(servoY_pin, 50)
pwm_y.start(1)
sleep(1.5)

# Set up serial communication with weight cells
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0", baudrate=9600, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
                    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS)
# Set up start stop
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN)
# Set up GPIO pins for cell selection
GPIO.setup(2, GPIO.OUT, initial=0)
GPIO.setup(3, GPIO.OUT, initial=0)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.output(2, 0)
GPIO.output(3, 0)

# Define the servo ranges
x_range = [-45, 45]
y_range = [-45, 45]


# Define the servo position limits
min_pos_x = -45
max_pos_x = 45
min_pos_y = -45
max_pos_y = 45

# Define the update interval for servo positions
update_interval = 1

# Define global variables for weight and servo positions
cell0_weight = 0.0
cell1_weight = 0.0
cell2_weight = 0.0
cell3_weight = 0.0
weight_front = 0.0
weight_left = 0.0
weight_right = 0.0
weight_back = 0.0
total_weight = 0.0
weight_diff = 0.0
last_total_weight = 0.0
last_weight_front = 0.0
last_weight_left = 0.0
last_weight_right = 0.0
last_weight_back = 0.0
pos_x = 0.0
pos_y = 0.0
last_weight_c0 = 0.0
last_weight_c1 = 0.0
last_weight_c2 = 0.0
last_weight_c3 = 0.0

#
def goal():
    if GPIO.input(17) == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
        
def start():
    if GPIO.input(4) == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
# Define a function to calculate the servo duty cycle for a given angle
def calculate_duty_cycle(angle):
    pulse_width = angle * 10 + servo_pulse
    duty_cycle = pulse_width / 20000.0 * 100.0
    return duty_cycle


# Define a function to select a cell for weight measurement
def selectCell(cellNr):
    if cellNr == 2:
        GPIO.output(2, 0)
        GPIO.output(3, 1)

    if cellNr == 3:
        GPIO.output(2, 1)
        GPIO.output(3, 1)
        
    if cellNr == 0:
        GPIO.output(2, 0)
        GPIO.output(3, 0)

    if cellNr == 1:
        GPIO.output(2, 1)
        GPIO.output(3, 0)
    return


# Define a function to get the weight of a cell
def getValue(cell):
        sleep(0.02)
        selectCell(cell)
        values = bytearray([83, 73, 13, 10])  # Request Weight value  ASCII 83 = S, 73 = I, 13 = CR(Carrige Return) 10 = LF(Line Feed)
        ser.write(values)
        msg = b''
        received = ser.read()
        while received != b'\n':
            msg += received
            received = ser.read()
        msg += received
        msg_parts = msg.split()
        if msg ==  b'S -\r\n':
            return 0.0
        try:
            msg = msg_parts[2].decode().strip()
            return float(msg)
        except (ValueError,IndexError):
            print("Except")
            return 0.0
            
    
    
step_size_x = 0.0
step_size_y = 0.0
# Define the servo step sizes
def stepsize():
    sleep(0.02)
    global total_weight, step_size_x, step_size_y
    step_size_x = total_weight * 0.01
    step_size_y = total_weight * 0.01
    


# Define a function to update the servo positions based on weight distribution
def update_servos():
    sleep(0.02)
    global weight_front, weight_left, weight_right, weight_back, total_weight, weight_diff, \
        last_total_weight, last_weight_front, last_weight_left, last_weight_right, last_weight_back, \
        pos_x, pos_y, last_weight_c0, last_weight_c1,last_weight_c2,last_weight_c3,step_size_x,step_size_y

    # Measure the weights on all cells
    
    cell0_weight = float(getValue(0))  # bottom right
    cell1_weight = float(getValue(1))  # top right
    cell2_weight = float(getValue(2))  # top left
    cell3_weight = float(getValue(3))  # bottom left
    
    stepsize()
    # Calculate the weight distribution on each axis
   
    weight_x = (cell2_weight + cell1_weight) - (cell3_weight + cell0_weight)  # weight distribution on the X-axis
    weight_y = (cell3_weight + cell2_weight) - (cell0_weight + cell1_weight)    # weight distribution on the Y-axis
    total_weight = cell0_weight + cell1_weight + cell2_weight + cell3_weight  
    
    
    # Update the weight differences since the last update
    weight_diff = total_weight - last_total_weight
    weight_front_diff = weight_front - last_weight_front
    weight_left_diff = weight_left - last_weight_left
    weight_right_diff = weight_right - last_weight_right
    weight_back_diff = weight_back - last_weight_back
 
    # Calculate the new servo positions based on the weight differences and step sizes
    new_pos_x = pos_x + weight_x * step_size_x
    new_pos_y = pos_y + weight_y * step_size_y
        
    
    # Limit the servo positions within the allowed range
    if new_pos_x > max_pos_x:
        new_pos_x = max_pos_x
    elif new_pos_x < min_pos_x:
        new_pos_x = min_pos_x

    if new_pos_y > max_pos_y:
        new_pos_y = max_pos_y
    elif new_pos_y < min_pos_y:
        new_pos_y = min_pos_y

    # Update the servo positions
    pwm_x.ChangeDutyCycle(calculate_duty_cycle(new_pos_x))
    pwm_y.ChangeDutyCycle(calculate_duty_cycle(new_pos_y))

    # Save the weight values and servo positions for the next update
    last_total_weight = total_weight
    last_weight_front = weight_front
    last_weight_left = weight_left
    last_weight_right = weight_right
    last_weight_back = weight_back
    last_weight_c0 = cell0_weight
    last_weight_c1 = cell1_weight
    last_weight_c2 = cell2_weight
    last_weight_c3 = cell3_weight
    pos_x = new_pos_x
    pos_y = new_pos_y

    

  



I tried to set the delays higher.

Try putting the GPIO stuff in another thread.
